# Samsung G9 not working with MacbBook Pro 2012

Tags: display, hdmi

I was using M1 Apple Macbook Pro but had to sell it for some reason but now I am back on my Macbook Pro 2012. I tried using the display port to HDMI on SAMSUNG - Odyssey G95 but my MacBook seems to freeze and when I take the cable off the MacBook it is working. But the monitor doesn't even display.

Why is it happening

Comment: Does the Samsung Odessey G95 have display ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older Macs will often require two cables and Picture-by-Picture mode for it to work. On a newer mac, Thunderbolt ports can handle the connection.

Try to use two DisplayPort cables to accomplish this, not HDMI of any sort.

Macbook Pro 2012 [info](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp649?locale=en_US).

Comment: The MacBook 2012 doesn’t have DisplayPort. It the following connector and expansion slot
FireWire 800 port (up to 800 Mbps)
Two USB 3 ports (up to 5 Gbps)
Thunderbolt port (up to 10 Gbps)

Do I need to buy converter?

Comment: Hi, can you expand on your answer with my comment pls?

Comment: Yes you'll need a thunderbolt to HDMI cable or Display port adapter.

Comment: Moshi USB-C to DisplayPort Cable - https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HLR62ZM/A/moshi-usb-c-to-displayport-cable?fnode=15bdc166ee74b4896925168addcb43e21b7e3f6d8a98b88bf54af3bd3f535a4402f4672eed78bd725aa4a96aefa847b94941549983032f104deda406c115c213a6724271a3778fe6ad5ba4339e7b475522e7243c27bca54d5f6ec18ba3536676577cdc162a402022f39012aa4d332770&fs=f=adapter&fh=459d%252B45b0

Comment: Belkin USB-C to HDMI Adapter - https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKQ22ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter?fnode=15bdc166ee74b4896925168addcb43e21b7e3f6d8a98b88bf54af3bd3f535a4402f4672eed78bd725aa4a96aefa847b94941549983032f104deda406c115c213a6724271a3778fe6ad5ba4339e7b475522e7243c27bca54d5f6ec18ba3536676577cdc162a402022f39012aa4d332770&fs=f=adapter&fh=459d%252B45b0

Comment: You mention no HDMI in answer but u recommended thunderbolt to HDMI

Comment: I thought you had a DisplayPort present on your device. Since you don't a thunderbolt port can be used as a display connector. Thunderbolt to HDMI is to connect the HDMI to the Samsung device.

Answer (score 0):

I was dying with this.

The new G9 doesn't play well with macbook Pros when the Dlink is set to 1.4

Go into the menu settings of the monitor while switch to the display port of choice and set it to 1.2